# Create custom event, like ionicPlatform.ready() or document.ready()

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app in which I use a database. I want to fill this database with the contents of a file.
This part I got working. I want to create a `DB.ready()` event, much like the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` or `document.ready()`, as I need to wait until the database is loaded until I query it.

I am fairly new to Ionic, and to the concept of Promises, so it might be something simple.

I've gotten it to work in Android, but iOS keeps returning an error in the query with "*someTablename does not exist*". I've placed multiple `console.log()`, and according to those everything is fine.

Could anyone tell me which part I did incorrect, or another method if that is more common in this situation (again, I'm new, so don't know what is common)?
I expected to get "`query`" logged every query, but it doesn't do that, is that significant?

```
// L35_DB - Databaseclass for apps
.factory('L35_DB', ['$ionicPlatform','$cordovaFile','$cordovaSQLite', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaFile,$cordovaSQLite) {
    var L35_DB = {db_start : false};
    //-------------------------------------
    DB_READY = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        console.log("query");
        if( L35_DB.db_start ){console.log("b"); resolve("Stuff worked!"); }
        else{
            var filename='fileWithDB.db';
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                if( window.cordova ){
                    return window.plugins.sqlDB.copy(filename, 0, 
                        function(info){ loadDB(filename).then( function(){ console.log("First load", info);  resolve("DB loaded?"); }) }, 
                        function(info){ loadDB(filename).then( function(){ console.log("Other loads", info); resolve("DB loaded?"); }) } 
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //-------------------------------------
    // Load the file
    function loadDB(filename){
        var loading = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(
                                        {name: filename, location: 'default'}, 
                                        function(){
                                            console.log("loadDB success"); // <--- fired
                                            L35_DB.db_start = true; // true, so next call we don't do all this
                                            resolve("DB ready loading");
                                        },
                                        function(err){ reject(err);}
                                    );
        });
        return loading;
    }
    //-------------------------------------
    // Query -
    var _query = function(query,values){
        if( !L35_DB.db_start ){
            console.error("DB not init");
            return false;
        }
        else if( window.cordova ){
            values = values || [];
            var actualQuery = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                db.executeSql(query, values, resolve, reject);
            })
            return actualQuery;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------
    return {
        query : _query
    };
}])
```

Throughout my app I do:

```
DB_READY.then(function () {
  L35_DB.query("SELECT * FROM systems").then(function (result) {
    // Something something something darkside
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and digging, turns out [`window.plugins.sqlDB.copy()`](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) was the culprit.

The 2nd value, location, can be changed. It defaults to `0`, but for iOS it has to be `2`. After this change, everything work exactly as expected.

*This function should preload the database for Android and iOS, assumed a bit too early it actually did.*